# IntelliJ 2019 throwing java.lang.NullPointerException error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, websphere-8

I'm running IntelliJ 2019.1, deploying app to a local Websphere server v8.5.5. My app had been working up to this point - able to build artifacts/projects and deploy to local server, either selecting to Run or Debug. But now am getting the error "Error running admin process:
Message: java.lang.NullPointerException Stack trace: com.intellij.javaee.process.common.JavaeeProcessUtilException: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.intellij.javaee.process.common.MethodInvocator.invoke(MethodInvocator.java:47) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess.processRequest(JavaeeProcess.java:112) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess.run(JavaeeProcess.java:52) at com.intellij.javaee.oss.process.JavaeeProcess.main(JavaeeProcess.java:31) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.intellij.j2ee.webSphere.agent.WebSphereAgent.createClient(WebSphereAgent.java:82) at com.intellij.j2ee.webSphere.agent.WebSphereAgent.connect(WebSphereAgent.java:51) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611) at com.intellij.javaee.process.common.MethodInvocator.invoke(MethodInvocator.java:41) ... 3 more "

I'm also seeing this error during the server startup - "[Fatal Error] :10:33: Character reference "&#21" is an invalid XML character."

Any suggestions?

Comment: A similar issue was resolved recently: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-320285/Wildfly-28-NoSuchMethodError-org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClientFactory.create. Please update IntelliJ IDEA at https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html and see if it helps.

Comment: I'm running Intellij 2019.1 and NO Wildfly. Also, I'm using Maven.

Comment: 2019.1 is way too old and may not support your app server version. Please update to the latest IntelliJ IDEA release and report if it helps.

Comment: So the inference is it is a problem "just waiting to happen" (because of the age of the tool)?

Comment: Find where you have that character entity reference in a document or something's name/ID and remove it?

Comment: We analyzed your stacktrace and found that a similar issue was fixed in the more recent IntelliJ IDEA versions. It makes sense to give it a try in order not to waste time on investigating the already resolved problems. If it still happens in the current release, please file a new bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA with the IDE logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data) and the full log from the IntelliJ IDEA run console when the server is started. Specify the exact app server version you are using and if it can be reproduced with the default server settings.